# Bootstrap Modal turns off scrolling, but doesn't turn it back on when dismissed

Tags: meteor, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a Meteor app using the [nemo64:bootstrap](https://atmospherejs.com/nemo64/bootstrap) package with the following config:

```
{"modules": {
    "normalize":            true,
    "print":                true,

    "scaffolding":          true,
    "type":                 true,
    "code":                 false,
    "grid":                 true,
    "tables":               true,
    "forms":                true,
    "buttons":              true,

    "glyphicons":           true,
    "button-groups":        true,
    "input-groups":         true,
    "navs":                 true,
    "navbar":               true,
    "breadcrumbs":          false,
    "pagination":           false,
    "pager":                false,
    "labels":               true,
    "badges":               true,
    "jumbotron":            false,
    "thumbnails":           false,
    "alerts":               true,
    "progress-bars":        true,
    "media":                false,
    "list-group":           false,
    "panels":               true,
    "wells":                false,
    "close":                true,

    "component-animations": true,
    "dropdowns":            true,
    "modals":               true,
    "tooltip":              true,
    "popovers":             true,
    "carousel":             true,

    "affix":                true,
    "alert":                true,
    "button":               true,
    "collapse":             true,
    "scrollspy":            true,
    "tab":                  true,
    "transition":           true,

    "utilities":            true,
    "responsive-utilities": true
}}
```

In one of my pages I have a modal that asks the user to confirm a user delete:

```
<div class="modal fade confirmRemoveUserModal confirmRemoveUserModal_{{this._id}}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="confirmRemoveUserModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="confirmRemoveUserModalLabel">Confirm User Removal</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        Are you sure you want to remove {{this.username}} permenently?
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">No/Cancel</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btnConfirmRemoveUser">Yes!</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Which is triggered from a button.  When the modal pops up, the background is greyed (expected) and scrolling of the background is turned off (also expected).  But after I dismiss the modal via JavaScript, the page is "stuck" in the location it was in, and scrolling is broken.  Even if I move off of that page (I used page loosely here, it's really never moved off the "page" since it's a meteor route) and back, the stuck page is still stuck in the same location.  If I dismiss via the data attributes on the `No/Cancel` button things work just fine.

Here is the code for handing the confirmation:

```
'click .btnConfirmRemoveUser': function(event, tmpl) {
  tmpl.$('.confirmRemoveUserModal').modal('hide');
  var username = this.username;
  Meteor.call('removeUser', this._id, function(err, result) {
    if (err) {
      createDismissibleAlert('An error occurred trying to remove the user ' + username + ': ' + err, 'danger', $('#adminAlerts'));
    } else {
      createDismissibleAlert('User ' + username + ' was removed.', 'success', $('#adminAlerts'));
    }
  });
}
```

I have observed the behavior in Chrome's Dev Tools, and I can see that the `modal-open` class gets applied the the `body` element when the modal is open, and gets removed when it is canceled, but remains when it is dismissed via the above JavaScript.  I have Google'd around to see if anyone is experiencing the same issue, but so far nothing.  I have a feeling it is because I have multiple copies of the same modal on my page.

Comment: For those that stumble across this same behavior, my temporary fix is to simply remove the class after I dismiss the modal via JS.  It's not ideal, in my opinion, but it works for now.

Comment: This worked for me too. Thanks.